# AutoResizing header & Cell in Programmatically UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, swift5

I have UIViewTable created programmatically
I customised the headers and cell look via Extension.
All I need is to make the large amount of texts displayed in header/cell to be viewed with:

> ```
> lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping // enable multi line
> numberOfLines = 0 // for Automatic size
> ```

I nearly used everything, but nothing is working.

I used:

> ```
> self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
> self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
> ```

I put:

> ```
> override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
>     return 100
>     }
> ```

I also did:

> ```
> override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
>         return UITableView.automaticDimension
>     }
> ```

Nothing seems to work

here is my Extension:

> extension indexController {
>
> ```
>     override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
>         return sections.count
>
>     }
>
>     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
>         let subDatas = sections[section].sub_catigories // [1]
>         return subDatas?.count ?? 0
>
>
>     }
>
>
>
>     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
>         let currentSection = sections[indexPath.section]
>         let currentSubdata = currentSection.sub_catigories?[indexPath.row]
>         //print(currentSubdata!.id)
>
>
>         let vc = indexControllerTwo()
>         vc.catNumber = currentSubdata!.id
>         vc.sectionTitle = currentSubdata?.name
>         navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
>
>     }
>
>
>     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
>         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath)
>
>         // [2]
>         let currentSection = sections[indexPath.section]
>         let currentSubdata = currentSection.sub_catigories![indexPath.row]
>
>         // use listCell
>         guard let titleCell = cell as? listCell else {
>             return cell
>         }
>
>         titleCell.titleLabel.text = currentSubdata.name
>         titleCell.listCount.text = "\(currentSubdata.number_of_subcatigories ?? 0)"
>
> //        titleCell.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 3
> //        titleCell.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
> //        titleCell.titleLabel.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
> //        titleCell.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
>
>
> //        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200.0
> //        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
>
>
>
>         cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
>
>         return cell
>     }
> ```

Please note that: listCell is just for customization and constraint
and here it is:

> ```
> import UIKit
>
> class listCell: UITableViewCell {
>
>     var safeArea: UILayoutGuide!
>     let imageCell = UIImageView()
>     let titleLabel = UILabel()
>     let subTitleLabel = UILabel()
>     let listCount = UILabel()
>
>
>
>     override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
>         super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
>         setupView()
>     }
>
>     required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
>         fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
>     }
>
>     func setupView(){
>         safeArea = layoutMarginsGuide
>         setupTitleLabel()
>         setupListCount()
>
>     }
>
>
>
>     func setupTitleLabel(){
>         addSubview(titleLabel)
>         titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
>         NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
>             titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.leadingAnchor),
>             titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 7)
>             ])
>
>
>         titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "verdana-Bold", size: 16)
>
>
>
>     }
>
>
>
>     func setupListCount(){
>         addSubview(listCount)
>         listCount.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
>         NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
>             listCount.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.trailingAnchor, constant: -30),
>             listCount.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: -11)
>             ])
>
>
>         listCount.font = UIFont(name: "verdana", size: 10)
>
>     }
>
>
>
>
> }
> ```

Please help me make the header and cell text field to be auto resizing.
thanks for your time.

Comment: It looks like you're missing some constraints in the cell. Add a bottom constraint to the listCount UILabel and by that you're forcing the content to be well sized: titleLabel (top, leading) && listCount (top to titleLabel.bottom, leading, bottom to superview). You also should add trailing constraints to avoid the text from going outside the label superview.